# How to open page in new window/tab or in same window/tab depending on Login success?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, forms, iframe

I have Login page wich is IFrame. If user successfuly logs in i want to open new page with his personal content, and if not I want error message displayed inside same iFrame.

This is my code:

```
<form class="register-form" runat="server" id='form1' target="_blank">
      <div class="input username">
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbUsername" runat="server" type="text" value="Username"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
        <div class="input password">
          <asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" value="Password" type="text"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
      <div class="submit">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSignIn" type="button" OnClick="btnSignIn_Click">
        </asp:Button>
      </div>
</form>
```

As you can see i initially set forms target attribute to "_blank", and plan to change it dynamically.

This is my onclick event in code behind:

```
protected void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.Providers["CmsMembershipProvider"].ValidateUser(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text))
        {
            Session["Username"] = tbUsername.Text.ToString();
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tbUsername.Text, true);         
            Response.Redirect("../Pages/MyProjects.aspx");
        }
        else {
            btnSignIn.OnClientClick = "openInSameWindow()";
            Msg.Text = "Login failed. Please check your user name and password and try again.";
        }
    }
```

and this is simple js function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function openInSameWindow() {
            var myForm = document.getElementById('form1');
            myForm.target = '_self';
        }
</script>
```

Page always opens in new tab/window.
I figured out that form already opens in new page before i set target to "_self" from code behind.

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: I am confused, your code appears to be Javascript executing on the client, yet you say you are `setting target to "_self" from code behind`?

Comment: Well I call js function from code behind, it technically executes on client but it is called on server side.

Answer (score 0):

> Page always opens in new tab/window. I figured out that form already
>   opens in new page before i set target to "_self" from code behind.

You are right. The ASP.net code gets executed AFTER target="_blank" is used for form. So your setting of target="_self" is wrong.

One solution for the problem you have is to use POPUP window to show the "../Pages/MyProjects.aspx" page.

Otherwise, I would prefer it if you can show "../Pages/MyProjects.aspx" in same window outside IFRAME. Otherwise keep the user in iframe showing appropriate message.

For first approach you will have to open the popup when user submits the form i.e. `form.onsubmit` handler. And on successful login set the location of POPUP to "Pages/MyProjects.aspx" otherwise close the POPUP. Ofcourse don't set target="_blank"

For second approach also don't set target (i.e. it should be _self) and on successful login set location like following.

```
window.top.location = "Pages/MyProjects.aspx"
```

such that your earlier function becomes

```
function openInSameWindow() {
  window.top.location = 'Pages/MyProjects.aspx';
}
```

when there are errors, they will be displayed in iframe only.

Comment: I would prefer second approach. Where do you suggest to put `window.top.location = "Pages/MyProjects.aspx"`, it do same thing if i use it like mine old function.

Comment: That is exactly what i tried before I posted comment on your answer. Function openInSameWindow do not get to do anything, MyProjects.aspx page opens in iframe inside Home.aspx page.

Comment: I haven't used ASP.net for some years so I can not give you exact code. But else part in you ASP.net code needs to be changed to return a page having a script that will execute window.top.location = ".."